# Shapefile text field unicode

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3

I used ArcGIS 10.3.1 to create shapefile with a text field with 5 length. When I entered a unicode text with 5 characters, ArcGIS lost the last 3 chars (saved only 2 beginning chars).

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you supply a screen grab of the properties and the table?

Comment: UTF-8 works in 1-6 byte codepoints, but dBase width is *bytes* -- If you want 5 codepoints, you'd need to define as wide as *30* width.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Desktop has a only certain amount of unicode support, which relies heavily on the data. I know fGDB Feature Classes support Unicode by default. I don't think shapefiles do. I made a 5 character text field in a shapefile and it could only store 1 of my 5 enclosed alpha numeric unicode characters. Where as the fGDB FC works perfectly on the same test.

I did some digging and found these antiquated shapefile formats are not great at unicode, in fact ***unicode support is not enabled by default***. You have to change the registry to enable it:

[Unicode in ArcGIS - Shapefiles](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27345)